# PGFPlots: Make Tick Labels Small Caps

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    title={Test},
symbolic x coords={SmallCaps, MoreSmallCaps},
xtick=data,
    ]
    
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(SmallCaps,0.5)(MoreSmallCaps,0.25)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(SmallCaps,0.5)(MoreSmallCaps,0.25)};

\legend{Series 1,Series 2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to force the symbolic x coords appear on a plot as all small caps?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `xticklabel style`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    title={Test},
symbolic x coords={SmallCaps, MoreSmallCaps},
xtick=data,
 xticklabel style={font=\scshape},
    ]
    
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(SmallCaps,0.5)(MoreSmallCaps,0.25)};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(SmallCaps,0.5)(MoreSmallCaps,0.25)};

\legend{Series 1,Series 2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this indeed solves the problem! Is there any other way to achieve this? I realised my MWE doesn't account for the fact that I am using Adobe Garamond Pro, a font that doesn't respond to \scshape

Comment: @Craig Please ask a new question which shows how you load your font.